# Timer Installation

Tags: electrical

I am trying to wire an in wall timer and am confused about the neutral wire. It's a single pole switch on a multi circuit in a multi gang box. The timer wants me to connect a neutral wire, but when I undo the neutral bundle and connect the one I think is for the light I want on the timer, it doesn't work (the light won't turn on).  What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box, and the make and model of your timer?

Comment: Single pole switches don't necessarily have neutrals present in the box.   They also make mechanical timer switches that don't need neutral, the human powers them with her strength.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't seperate**

All neutrals stay in the bundle.  **Add** the neutral from the switch to that bundle.

Your wording suggests you are removing the neutral coming from the light and making a one on one connection to the timers neutral.  Instead you need to add the timers neutral to that bundle, leaving all neutrals connected together in the bundle.